# Use AssertJ Swing test from Cucumber

Tags: java, swing, cucumber, assertj

I have a simple unit test to make sure the main window of the application is undcorated:

```java
public class MainWindowUT extends AbstractMainWindowTest {

    @Test
    public void whenApplicationIsStarted_thenMainFrameIsUndecorated() {
        @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
        Boolean isUndecorated = GuiActionRunner.execute(() -> window.target().isUndecorated());
        assertThat(isUndecorated).isTrue();
    }
}
```

AbstractMainWindowTest is:

```java
public abstract class AbstractMainWindowTest extends AssertJSwingJUnitTestCase {

    protected FrameFixture window;

    @Override
    protected void onSetUp() {
        ScaleRuler frame = GuiActionRunner.execute(() -> new ScaleRuler());
        window = new FrameFixture(robot(), frame);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

ScaleRuler is my frame, that for the moment does nothing, just setUndecorated(true). The test runs fine.
How do I perform the same test from Cucumber?

```java
public final class WindowAspectSteps {

    @Then("the main window should be undecorated")
    public void checkMainWindowIsUndecorated() {
        //????
    }
}
```

I tried to make WindowAspectSteps to extend AbstractMainWindowTest, but the window variable remains null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Before` annotation of JUnit (`@org.junit.Before`) doesn't work with Cucumber.
Cucumber has its [own @Before annotation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/) (`@cucumber.api.java.Before`) :

In fact JUnit and Cucumber are really two distinct test runner platforms and so have their own test runners and associated facilities (while some are common in terms of logic).

As a workaround, try to add the 2 distinct `@Before` annotations (junit's and cucumber's) on the setup method of the test abstract class or create two distinct methods : one with `@cucumber.api.java.Before` and another with `@org.junit.Before` which both delegate to a common method that do the setup processing.